# ORDER BY more than one column in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table of a classroom with 3 column: Name, Class and Age. When do

```
Select * from students
```

It shows these value

```
Name           |   Class        |  Age   
John           |      D         |   7   
Mary           |      A         |   10  
Jenny          |      B         |   9  
Peter          |      D         |   7
```

I want to sort the values with these conditions
- First, Order by Age DESC
- If there are more 2 people have same age, Order by Name ASC

I use these command

```
Select * from students order by Age Desc, Name ASC .
```

but it doesn't sort Class too. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you paste your required result?

Comment: My expected result is
Mary | A | 10    
Jenny |B| 9    
John |D| 7    
Peter |D| 7

Comment: How you want to sort class?

Comment: `but it doesn't sort Class too` , here you are not included the class field in sort order.

Comment: Can you [edit] your  question with current output vs desired output?

Comment: `... order by Class, Age desc, Name` still won't sort by shoe size, but it will put classmates together. Note that _only_ your specified order is guaranteed, anything else is happenstance and may vary from time to time. For example, you might get results grouped by `Class` without explicitly adding it to the `order by` clause, but adding an index to the table or installing a SQL Server update could change the order of the results as long as the new order respects the `order by` clause.

Comment: [Your query returns the expected result](http://rextester.com/TSAW51821).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort by class first, then age, then name:

```
Select Name, Class, Age
FROM students 
ORDER BY class ASC, Age DESC, Name ASC;
```

Should output:

```
Name           |   Class        |  Age   
Mary           |      A         |   10  
Jenny          |      B         |   9  
John           |      D         |   7 
Peter          |      D         |   7
```

To sort by age first, then class, then name:

```
Select Name, Class, Age
FROM students 
ORDER BY Age DESC, class ASC, Name ASC;
```

Should output the same, because the data provided happens to sort the same way using this alternate criteria.

```
Name           |   Class        |  Age   
Mary           |      A         |   10  
Jenny          |      B         |   9  
John           |      D         |   7 
Peter          |      D         |   7
```

Comment: sorting by class then by age is meaningless for this sample data since there are no records with the same class but different ages, and anyway sorting by class ascending will give the exact same result as sorting by age descending.

Comment: Agreed, but with a larger data set, I believe it will align with the requested format as you may eventually have a child who is a year older or younger than the rest in their class.

Comment: In the 4 years I've been a member of this community, I've learned never to assume what the question doesn't specifically states. You might get it right some times, but most of the times you will just find out too late your assumption was wrong. (I'm not saying this is the case here, just as a rule of thumb).

Comment: I included class, because of the phrase, "but it doesn't sort Class too. Is there anyone can help me?". And since I was making an assumption, I offered two ways in case it was not requested. I suppose my alternate way could omit 'class'. I do appreciate the constructive comment, I would agree had it not been for that last sentence in the question.

Comment: @DanSorensen I think your answer is reasonable. But when there is more than 3 field how to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query.

First use Asc then second use Desc.

```
Select * from students order by  Name ASC, Age Desc,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tab table(Name     varchar(30),  Class   char(1),    Age int   )

insert into @tab
select 'John'    ,    'D'  , 7  
union all 
select 'Mary'    ,    'A'  , 10  
union all
select 'Jenny'   ,    'B' , 9  
union all
select 'Peter'   ,    'D'  , 7 

select * from @tab order by Age desc,name asc

Name    Class   Age
Mary    A       10
Jenny   B       9
John    D       7
Peter   D       7
```